# Large amount of redis keys are evicted unexpectedly even though memory not reach max configuration

Tags: redis, backend, production, evict

I am experiencing a very strange case happen in production with redis, a large amount of redis keys are evicted unexpectedly even though memory not reach max configuration.

Current redis setting is max mem = 7GB, volatile-ttl.
Most of the keys are set a TTL when store to Redis.

Below graph showing a large drop in redis key eventhough memory at the time was only 3.5GB (<< 7GB)

[image: Redis keys graph]
[image: Redis mem graph]

According to my understanding, Redis would evict keys only when memory reach max-mem. And even when it does, it will only drop keys gradually according to the need for inserting new keys.

Thank you very much!

Comment: "Most of the keys are set a TTL" - the graph suggests the opposite, but perhaps the keys reached their expiry? Expiry and eviction are not the same thing.

Comment: Yup normally all expired keys will be gradually removed. Do you know any case that keys are evicted even when memory does not reach max?

Comment: Nope, keys do not get evicted just because.